# SOQL join between two standard objects

Tags: salesforce, soql

All i want to do is to retrieve information from two standard objects `Account` and `Case`. For I have tried joins(which later I found does not work with SOQL), relationships (which does not exist in my case. except for default relationship). Following is another attempt using sub query: (By default relationship I mean that `Id` in `Account` is same as `AccountId` in `Case`)

`Select Phone,City__c,CreatedDate,Name,
(SELECT Customer_Satisfaction_Level__c,Product_Category__c FROM AccountId__r)
FROM Account;`

Also, SOQL does not allow aliases which would have helped me as I am working with QlikView.
Please Help!

Comment: can you ask this question on salesforce.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0):

Use This Below Query...Hope itz might be favourable for you

Select Phone,City__c,CreatedDate,Name, (SELECT Customer_Satisfaction_Level_*c FROM AccountId*_r where AccountId__r.ID=ID ) as Customer_Satisfaction_Level__c,(SELECT Product_Category_*c FROM AccountId*_r where AccountId__r.ID=ID ) as Product_Category__c FROM Account;

Comment: nope.it does not work. AccountId__r was a relationship i thought existed but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can select Accounts with related Cases like this:

```
List<Account> accounts = [Select Id, (Select Id From Cases) From Account];
```

And then iterate over results:

```
for (Account account : accounts) {
   for (Case case : account.Cases) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: i want names from account and the case detail from cases. hence, a join between the two.

Comment: SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name, some_field1, some_field2 FROM Cases) FROM Account.
And in the loop instead of ... you can get this fields like this:
SYSTEM.DEBUG('Account name - '+account.Name);
SYSTEM.DEBUG('Related Case name - '+case.Name);